# Where does aspell store my own added words?

Tags: spell-checking, aspell

Where does aspell store my own added words (with the 'a' option) and how can I manipulate this list? I hope aspell stores this in a separate dictionary, separate from the language dictionary.

The background is that I want to review this list on a regular interval.

Answer (score 3):

Typically `~/.aspell.<lang>.pws`. For example using

```
aspell -d pt_PT -c file
```

(you are using language pt_PT) the added words will be stored in

```
$HOME/.aspell.pt_PT.pws
```